# Llenar modal con datos mediante ajax y servicios web

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, restful

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo un proyecto en donde debo llenar una ventana modal desde la base de datos mediante Ajax, explicaré el proyecto, tengo los servicios web rest en C#  y lo estoy consumiendo desde Java 2EE con servlet y una clase llamada ServiciosWeb, pero al momento de hacer el Ajax en el proyecto de Java, me dice que la url del metodo no la encuentra, este método es BuscarPorId(); entonces, al presionar el boton modificar el que aparece en la foto con un cuadro y una flecha, el boton tiene el id del elemento en el value=""; , entonces cuando yo lo presiono debiera buscar por ID el elemento en la base de datos, en una foto les dejaré el error que aparece.

```
$('.keyModal').click(function (){
       console.log("Modal esta abierto");
      $('#myModal').modal('show');

        var idFormulario = $(this).attrib('id'); //Tenemos el id del formulario

            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'Json',
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'BuscarMedicamentoPorId/',
                data: {id = idFormulario},
                success: function (r)
                {
                    console.log("Ejecutó metodo");
                    //Seteamos los input
                    $('#txtDescripcionEditar').val(r['DESCRIPCION']);
                    $('#txtContenidoEditar').val(r['CONTENIDO']);
                    $('#txtGramajeEditar').val(r['GRAMAJE']);

                    //Seteamos los valores <select>
                    $("select#seleccioneTipoEditar").val(r['MED_IDTIPOMEDICAMENTO']).attr('selected', true);
                    $("select#seleccioneViaEditar").val(r['VIAADMIN_IDVIAADMIN']).attr('selected', true);
                }
            });
        });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: haa ya, gracias por el dato.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema esta en que no estas extrayendo el `id` el hacer esto:

```
var idFormulario = $(this);
```

estas obteniendo un elemento del `DOM`, que es el botón que has hecho clic, si lo que quieres es obtener el id del elemento cambia esa linea por esto:

```
var idFormulario = $(this).attr('id');//buscas el atributo que contiene el identificador
```

y para enviarlo desde el ajax en el atributo `data` has este cambio:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: {id = idFormulario}
  ...
});
```

Comment: gracias juankGlezz, ya cambié ese detalle, pero subí otro error, que es el que me daba, que no reconocía la URL del método que quiero utilizar...